# How to install native NuGet package to .NET6 project

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to migrate our WinForms project from .NET Framework to .NET6. We had all dependencies linked from dlls since the solution was designed for SharpDevelop.

I wanted to use advantages of NuGet tool, but I am facing a problem of not compatible package. It throws

```
NU1202: Package Basler.Pylon.NET.x64 6.2.0.18677 is not compatible with net6.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Basler.Pylon.NET.x64 6.2.0.18677 supports: native (native,Version=v0.0)
```

Clearing NuGet cache did not helped and my other googling was too general to find anything useful (*it's first time I'm facing native NuGet package*).

How can I link this package to my .NET6 WinForms library or is this package only for UWP applications?

Comment: Did you tried the `upgrade-assistant` tool? Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework). This is not a simple task and you should be somewhat familiar with NuGet and .NET6. Also keep attention, there are some namespaces that are not directly ported to current .NET versions, since the old versions did not try to be OS unspecific. .NET5 and later can run on windows and unix systems (i.e. System.Drawing uses GDI/Win32, that is not available under unix systems)

Comment: I have not tried the `upgrade-assistant` tool. Thank you for mentioning it, I will try it but I guess the tool won't help me with porting reference from a dll to a NuGet package. I know that nuget packages targets *.NET Framework* or *.NET Core* and there is also an alternative usable in both *.NET Standard*, but this is the first time I see nuget package targeting *native* and I don't know how to get it to the app.

Comment: I think that's gonna be difficult since I've never seen a working sample of referencing a native DLL via NuGet. Maybe you're lucky and you can wrap the native package into a .NET NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET Standard to add the Basler NuGet package, and call such library from the rest of your .NET >= 5 app. That's what I've done.

You might need to rework your solution dependencies, though. A .NET Standard package can be referenced from both .NET Framework and .NET >=5, but the reverse is not true, at least for .NET >= 5.